# control never seems to go in the if block

Tags: java

I find that the control never seems to go in if block that starts from "if(sqlquery.equals("1"))" when it actually returns to be true. What could be the reason to it and how should ! modify it ?My program code is :

```
//package searchbook;
    import java.io.*;
    import javax.servlet.*;
    import javax.servlet.http.*;
    import java.sql.*;
    import java.util.*;

    public class SearchBook extends HttpServlet {
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException,IOException{
    response.setContentType("text/html"); 
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
    List booklist=new ArrayList();
    Connection con = null;

    String url = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=" + "C:\\users\\ppreeti\\executive_db.accdb";

    String driver = "sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver";
    String user = "";
    String pass = "";
    String category="";
    category=request.getParameter("input");
    String sqlquery="select   Index1.link_id "    
            + "FROM Index1 "
            + " WHERE  Index1.index_name LIKE '%"+category+"%'  ";
    try
        {
            Class.forName(driver);
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
                try{
                    Statement st = con.createStatement();
                    System.out.println("Connection created 1");
                    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sqlquery);
                    System.out.println("Result retreived  1");
                    //System.out.println('"sqlquery"');
                }
                catch (SQLException s)
                {
                    System.out.println("SQL statement is not executed! "+ s);
                }
            }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    System.out.println("************");
    //String sqlq="";

    if(sqlquery.equals("1"))
    {
    String sqlq="select Section.Section_Name , Report.Report_Name , Report.Link, Contact.Contact_Name, Metrics.Metric_Name "
            + "FROM Section , Report , Contact,Metrics "
            + "WHERE Report.Contact_ID=Contact.Contact_ID and Report.Section_ID=Section.Section_ID  "
            + "and Report.Report_ID IN (SELECT Metrics.Report_ID FROM Metrics  WHERE Metrics.Metric_Name = Report.Report_ID') and Metrics.Metric_Segment = 'M' ";

    System.out.println("2nd query executed too !");
    try
    {
        Class.forName(driver);
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
            try
                {
                Statement st = con.createStatement();
                System.out.println("Connection created");
                ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sqlq);
                System.out.println("Result retreived  ");
                while (rs.next())
                {
                List<String> book=new ArrayList<String>();

                String Name=rs.getString("Section_Name");
                String reportName=rs.getString("Report_Name");
                String link=rs.getString("Link");
                String contactName=rs.getString("Contact_Name");
                String metricName=rs.getString("Metric_Name");
                //String reportId=rs.getString("Report_ID");

                /*String ind_id=rs.getString("index_name");
                String ind_name=rs.getString("link_id");*/

                book.add(Name);
                book.add(reportName);
                book.add(link);
                book.add(contactName);
                book.add(metricName);
                //book.add(reportId);

                /*book.add(ind_id);
                book.add(ind_name);*/

                booklist.add(book);
                }
            }
            catch (SQLException s)
            {
                System.out.println("SQL statement is not executed! "+ s);
            }
        }
    catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }}
    System.out.println("And it came here lastly !");
    request.setAttribute("booklist",booklist); 
    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/searchbook.jsp");
    dispatcher.forward(request, response); 
    }
    }
```

Comment: you are prininting the query .. not the result :S

Comment: which IDE do you use? Start debugging and you will soon know where the problem is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting your variable

```
String sqlquery="select   Index1.link_id "
            + "FROM Index1 "
            + " WHERE  Index1.index_name LIKE '%"+category+"%'  ";
```

and then comparing it to 1:

```
if(sqlquery.equals("1"))`
```

which will never be true

add a `String sqlResult = null;` right after your sqlquery declaration
and add a `sqlResult = rs.getString(1)` right after your

```
rs = st.executeQuery(sqlquery);
```

then compare with sqlResult instead of sqlQuery

Comment: Thank you for making me understand my mistake !

Comment: so I did that but now I'm getting another error ! java.lang.NullPointerException
 SearchBook.doPost(SearchBook.java:52)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:643)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)  Kindly help me !

Comment: the error is in the line :"String sqlq="select Section.Section_Name , Report.Report_Name , Report.Link, Contact.Contact_Name, Metrics.Metric_Name "
  + "FROM Section , Report , Contact,Metrics "
        + "WHERE Report.Contact_ID=Contact.Contact_ID and Report.Section_ID=Section.Section_ID  "
        + "and Report.Report_ID IN (SELECT Metrics.Report_ID FROM Metrics  WHERE Metrics.Metric_Name = Report.Report_ID') and Metrics.Metric_Segment = 'M' ";
"

Comment: it also generates the message "SQL statement is not executed! java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Invalid cursor state" in the console ! :(

Comment: It's another problem but at least I can spot a ' that comes from nowhere in your sql:
`WHERE Metrics.Metric_Name = Report.Report_ID')`  
  
Remove that quote after Report.Report_ID

Answer (score 0):

Your string `sqlquery` contains a `select` statement so will never be equal to `"1"`.

You need to check the result of your query, not the query string itself.

To do that, you're going to need to define `rs` (and the `Statement` as well, I believe) *before* the `try` block (so it stays in scope after that block), then evaluate it to see if it returned the data you desired.

How you do that depends on whether that `"1"` is meant to represent the number of rows returned or the data itself returned (from `Index1.link_id`).

Comment: but sqlqueary is a string variable, ryt ? so it should be true and can be compared with "1". Isn't it ?

Comment: Yes.  And "banana" can also be compared to "1".  But the result of that comparison will be a loud "not equals", even though "1" is the correct answer to "how many bananas are in my kitchen right now".

Comment: I defer to @David there, his answer is funnier than the one I was contemplating. Yes, you can compare strings but, if your intent is to compare the _result_ of the query with something, you should do that. _Not_ compare the actual query string itself.

Comment: so kindly enlighten me by telling me how it should be done ! :)

Comment: @user3436273, that's in the answer. You need to use `rs` to get the information you want.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it won't. `sqlquery` is a string containing the SQL-code (`"SELECT ..."`).

Answer (score 0):

I suspected that you are trying to compare "string" with "int" :

```
if(sqlquery.equals("1"))
```

So it will obviously not go inside the statement.

Instead you can try this

```
if(sqlquery != null)
```